# printf inside for loop

Tags: java, printf

I have been playing around with the printf method and I am confused with the output from this code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String[] names = {"Sam, John, George"};
    double[] balances = {1000.97,100.00,87.00};
    for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
        System.out.printf("Hello %s      this is your balance %.2f\n",names[i],balances[i]);
    }

}
The output: Hello Sam, John, George      this is your balance 1000.97
```

I expected three print statements in the console for each person.

Thank for any help.

Comment: You only have 1 string inside your array - "Sam, John, George". The commas are inside the string literal.

Answer (score 5):

`"Sam, John, George"` is one string.

You're missing some quotes. It should be:

```
String[] names = {"Sam", "John", "George"};
```

Comment: lol I am really tired, I don't know how I missed those. Thanks for your help.